# I want to send data from many clients to one stable client using Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, openshift, openshift-cartridge

Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var net = require('net');
var app = express();


//first of all connect to a stable client
var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
// do nothing here . what i want is to use this socket in 
// (following) app.get() function
});
server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');

//receive request from other clients
app.get('/', function (req, res) 
{
// retriving mobileNumber and message
var mobileNumber = req.query.mobileNumber;
var message      = req.query.message;

//now i want to send this data to the stable client
// to which i have connected earlier.
res.end();
});

app.listen(6544);
```

I want to send data to the previously connected socket whenever a new '/' request arrives.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that through one variable `var sock` as bellow.

```
var sock;
var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
   sock = socket;
});
server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');

app.get('/', function (req, res) 
{
    if (sock) {
        // use sock here
    }
});
```

Comment: thankyou for reply . It worked for localhost but i want to deploy it on openshift . Openshift gave me a url to access my nodejs app but not ip address. so is there any way to do that on openshift                                             please help me.

Comment: @NarayanChoudhary, Sorry, I am not familiar with Openshift. maybe you can ask another question for your new issue