# I want to connect to my node js application by ipaddress

Tags: openshift

I want to connect to my nodejs application through ipaddress which i have deployed on openshift.
following is the url of my app

```
http://myapp-nnms.rhcloud.com/
```

is this possible to connect through ip address

Comment: Probably not, as you're not likely to be the only user on that server. Why do you need this?

Comment: because i want this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35533118/i-want-to-send-data-from-many-clients-to-one-stable-client-using-node-js

Comment: i want a stable connection between node js and java socket.                           but http is connectionless . is there any other possible way to do that please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Usually these shared hosting servers use CNAME to resolve to your server. Means there will be many such server running for same IP, router decides to connect to your server based on host name. So its not possible. If you used your own dedicated server its possible.